# In C I keep outputting 0.0 in a 2D array

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

            //if there is no argument
            if(argc < 2) {
                    printf("Needs an argument\n");
                    return -1;

            }

            //training data
            char *fname = argv[1];

            //test data
            char *fname2 = argv[2];

            //pointer for training data
            FILE *fptr;

            //pointer for test data
            FILE *fptr2;

            //number of columns
            int column;

            //number of rows
            int row;

            //opens training data file and reads it
            fptr = fopen(fname, "r");

            //will scan the first line of training data
            //to store column of attributes and we add
            //1 more column for price 
            fscanf(fptr, "%d\n", &column);
            //add column for price
            column++;

            printf("Number of columns: %d\n", column);

            //will scan the second line of training data
            //to store number of rows
            fscanf(fptr, "%d\n", &row);

            printf("Number of rows: %d\n", row);

            //create the size of the array with row and column
            double arr[row][column];



            //store the 2d array
            for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
                            fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &arr[row][column]);
                            printf("%lf", arr[row][column]);
                    }
            }
```

I am trying to read and store a txt file into a 2d array but it keeps outputting 0.0000. So i guess there is something wrong with my code to store doubles. if you can help me find out whats wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING?

Comment: What is the file content? Also, why dont you check for success or failure of `fopen()`/ `fscanf()` calls?

Comment: `fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &arr[row][column]);` -> `fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &arr[i][j]);` and same for the `printf`

Comment: @kaylum That looks like the/an answer.

Comment: @ProgrammerHelp Please let me know if your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the comments by `@kaylum, @Yunnosch`. You use the wrong index to access your data in the loop. You should be using `i` and `j` instead of `row` and `column` because they are `constant` and in this case the maximum value of your row/column.

```
fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &arr[i][j]);
```

To avoid these kinds of mistakes, I normally choose more meaningful names for my variables.

For example, you wrote this here:

```
//number of columns
int column;

//number of rows
int row;
```

I wonder, why you have chosen a singular name for something that is actually pluralistic. It makes more sense to call it `columns` or even more specific `numberOfColumns` as you did in the comment. In this case, you don't need comments anymore. And if you do this as a general rule for methods, variables, etc. your code will much more readable. It really helped me to become a better developer.

I can also tell you why I like `numberOfColumns` better than `columns`. `columns` could refer to an integer or an array, whereas `numberOfColumns` is most likely an `int` since it would not make a whole lot of sense to be a `float` or `double` or even an `array` and it gives away that this is some sort of `constant` immediately.

Here is an example of how I might write it:

```
//store the 2d array
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOrRows; rowIndex++) {
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numberOfColumns; colIndex++) {
        fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &arr[rowIndex][colIndex]);
        printf("%lf", arr[rowIndex][colIndex]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your additional insight on variables names. Referring to the comment which outlined the technical solution ahead of your answer is good style. :-) Consider giving a name.